# Using Puppeteer&Python on Node.JS to solve captchas

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, puppeteer, captcha

I'm using puppeteer library to access some sites and leach data from their HTML files. for that manner, I've got a Python script that should help me solve each captcha if there is.

now, to run the Python script, I'm using python-shell from npm, and committing this:

```
   

 let options = {
        mode: 'text',
        args: [captchas[0].sitekey],
        scriptPath: path.resolve('bypass'),
        pythonPath: '/usr/bin/python',
    }
    console.log(`options.scriptPath`, options.scriptPath)

    PythonShell.run(
        `bypass/bypass.py`,
        options,
        (err, [, captchaKey]) => {
            if (err) throw err
            let solutions = [
                {
                    _vendor: captchas[0]._vendor,
                    id: captchas[0].id,
                    text: captchaKey,
                    hasSolution: true,
                },
            ]
            resolve({ solutions })
        }
    )
```

I've got this error -

```
    Solving captcha...
    options.scriptPath MY_PATH/backend/bypass
    file:///MY_PATH/backend/bypass/captchaBypasser.js:18
                (err, [, captchaKey]) => {
                ^
    
    TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
        at file:///MY_PATH/backend/bypass/captchaBypasser.js:18
        at PythonShell._endCallback (/MY_PATH/backend/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:254:20)
        at terminateIfNeeded (/MY_PATH/backend/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:209:39)
        at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/MY_PATH/backend/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:182:13)
```

---

I've tried also to use spawn of child_process, like this:

```
    const location = path.resolve('bypass/bypass.py')
    console.log(`python ${location} ${captchas[0].sitekey}`)

    const run = spawn('python', [location, captchas[0].sitekey])
    run.stdout.on('data', ([, captchaKey]) => {
        let solutions = [
            {
                _vendor: captchas[0]._vendor,
                id: captchas[0].id,
                text: captchaKey,
                hasSolution: true,
            },
        ]
        resolve({ solutions })
    })
```

and it appears to just crush without even an outcome.

---

So I've tried to try the actual command line:

```
    python /MY_PATH/backend/bypass/bypass.py ae7317...TOKEN...d0dab8b75
```

**BY THE WAY - I've TRYED ALSO python3 WITH VERSION 3.10.0**

And now I've got this error:

```
 
      from hcapbypass import bypass
      File "/MY_PATH/backend/bypass/hcapbypass.py", line 35
        def N_Data(req) -> str:
                        ^
```

---

So I tried to use the latest version of Python, 3.10.0, that came out like a few weeks ago, and that's the outcome:

```
    File "/MY_PATH/backend/bypass/bypass.py", line 4, in <module>
        captcha_solved = bypass(sys.argv[1], 'google.com', True)
    TypeError: bypass() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'
```

---

*For your full understanding, here is the bypass and the solver codes:*

**bypass.py**

```
    from hcapbypass import bypass
    import sys
    
    captcha_solved = bypass(sys.argv[1], 'google.com', True)
    print(captcha_solved)
```

**hcapbypass**
[Link to github](https://github.com/DanDev95/bypasser/blob/main/hcapbypass.py)

Does anyone know what to do?
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

OK, ive got the solution:

inside the hcapbypass.py file, the httpx module isn't presented, so I've created an environment with bin & lib folders to install it locally.

In addition, few functions got an argument that doesn't exist.

And of course, destructuring an array that is null / undefined - throws an error!